# How to use the DLookUp function and if it is the correct function for this job?

Tags: ms-access, vba, lookup

I have two tables in my database, and a form that is opened when the user logs in.

A text box in this form will display that users name e.g. "Ollie", I want another text box to display this users contracted hours from within the users table when the form is opened.

I have tried using the DLookUp form in the before update section however nothing happens? Below is an example of what I have tried.

```
=DLookUp("[ContractedHours]","tblUser","[Operator] =[tblUser]![UserLogin]")
```

So saying that the value in my form text box "Operator" is Ollie, the value in my table column "UserLogin" is Ollie, i'd like another text box on the form to display the contracted hours on the record for Ollie.

tblUser contains these columns

```
ID    UserLogin   Contracted Hours  Password
1      Ollie         8:00            *****
2      Ryan          5:00            *****
```

My form contains a text box that will equal either Ollie or Ryan, and I would like another text box that displays the relevant Contracted Hours.

Comment: There's very little information to go on here.  Normally, there are better ways to accomplish what you are doing, like joining `tblUser` in your form's underlying query so that you already have access to the login name without resorting to a `DLookUp`.  But it's hard to tell what the correct course of action is from the scant information you have provided.

Comment: Added an update that may be of some use, bit more information! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLookup will only work if you provide it a valid condition that allows it to identify a specific record in the table.  What you have provided is not a value; it's a reference to a column in a table.  There's no way for DLookup to know which record you are referring to.

Have a look at [this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) for some working examples.  Notice they all have a condition that points to a specific record:

```
DLookup("UnitPrice * Quantity", "Order Details", "OrderID = 10248")
```

or

```
DLookup("CustomerID", "Orders", "OrderID = Forms![Orders]!OrderID")
```

Comment: Is there another way I can go about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're going for a form-based parameter (like `Forms![Orders]!OrderID`, I strongly recommend keeping it inside the quotes. `DLookUp` can process these, and it avoids problems with null values and string values leading to invalid statements.

Answer (score 0):

It should read like:

```
=DLookUp("[ContractedHours]","tblUser","[UserLogin] = '" & Me!TextboxWithUserName & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your excerpt from table users, it's probably because you didn't include the space in the Contracted Hours column name in your DLookUp. Also, I would put your form call outside of the string.

Try:

```
=DLookUp("[Contracted Hours]","tblUser","[Operator] = '" & Forms![tblUser]![UserLogin] & "'")
```